# Scoped variables in transcluded block in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to do the following....

```
<parent>
   <div>{{animal}}</div>
</parent>

angular.component('parent',{
   template : '<div ng-repeat="animal in ['cats','dogs']">
                   <span ng-transclude></span>
               </div>';

});
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The angular reference manual [writes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion):

> Transclusion is the process of extracting a collection of DOM elements from one part of the DOM and copying them to another part of the DOM, while maintaining their connection to the original AngularJS scope from where they were taken.

That is, angular evaluates expressions contained in transcluded dom in the scope from which they were taken rather than the scope they were moved to, i.e. `animal` will not be evaluated in the scope introduced by the `ng-repeat` and hence most likely be `undefined`.

Comment: So is there no way to do this?

Comment: Not with transclusion, at any rate. And even if you get it to work, the code would be a puzzle for the future maintainer, as the definition of animal is hidden in a place most people would never think to check.